# Nightmare.JS on Heroku causes Timeout

Tags: node.js, heroku, nightmare

I'm building a website that when people put in their credentials to a website in the request part of the URL it will log them into that website and send back data about their account. Testing this code locally produces no errors and happens fairly quickly. I'm not sure what's causing it to time out on the server and not locally.

Here is the log file from `heroku logs`

```
2016-05-27T05:03:02.884921+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-05-27T05:03:02.884910+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-05-27T05:03:02.853598+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-05-27T05:03:02.854287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-05-27T05:03:05.766040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-05-27T05:03:08.021294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-05-27T05:03:10.308664+00:00 app[web.1]: Node app is running on port 54574
2016-05-27T05:03:11.710569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-27T05:03:12.491140+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 27 May 2016 05:03:12 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at server.js:16:21
2016-05-27T05:03:12.490421+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 27 May 2016 05:03:12 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at server.js:15:21
2016-05-27T05:03:28.689866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-05-27T05:03:30.932497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-05-27T05:03:42.447506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/getGrades?username=REDACTED&password= REDACTED" host=fantasyps.herokuapp.com request_id=e3cb4c15-09af-432c-beb7-e815784c162e fwd="69.122.17.44" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

The Profile contains a command to run this file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//routes go here
app.get('/getGrades', function(req, res) {
    function handleData(error, data) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else res.send(data);
    }
    var scrape = require('./scrape.js');
    var username = req.param('username');
    var password = req.param('password');
    scrape.scrape(username, password, handleData);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});

// start the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

And here is `scrape.js`

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
exports.scrape = vo(function*(username, password) {
    var nightmare = Nightmare({show: false});
    var info = yield nightmare
        .goto('http://ps01.bergen.org') // Go To Powerschool
        .type('[id=fieldAccount]', username) // Fill in Username Field
        .type('[id=fieldPassword]', password) // Fill in Password Field
        .click('[type=submit]') // Submit Form (Calls Hashing on click)
        .wait(200) // Wait for Page to Load (Prevents Error)
        .goto('http://ps01.bergen.org/guardian/home.html') // Go To the Grades Page
        .evaluate(function() { // Get Array like [[course info], [tri1 grades], [tri2 grades], [tri3 grades]]
            // GET COURSE NAMES AND FILTER NON-GPA AND ELECTIVE COURSES
            var courseInfo = [], tri1 = [], tri2 = [], tri3 = [], complete = [];
            var elements = document.querySelectorAll("tr td[align=left]");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].textContent.charAt(0) != "~" && (elements[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML != "&nbsp;" && elements[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML != "&nbsp;" && elements[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML != "&nbsp;")) {
                    courseInfo.push(elements[i].textContent);
                    tri1.push(elements[i].nextElementSibling.textContent); // Tri 1 Grade
                    tri2.push(elements[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent); // Tri 2 Grade
                    tri3.push(elements[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent); // Tri 3 Grade
                }
            }
            complete.push(courseInfo);
            complete.push(tri1);
            complete.push(tri2);
            complete.push(tri3);
            return complete;
        })
        yield nightmare.end();
        return info;
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but I do feel compelled to mention it: you never want someone to send you their username and password inside of URL parameters like you're doing here. This is really a bad security practice because those log files will contain that username/password in plain text, and those files are stored by Heroku and also some of your addon providers, meaning that you now have user credentials floating around in a lot of other people's systems. It's a lot better to have users supply this data to you in the body of a POST request.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this, but I just want to test if what I want to do is possible on heroku, I intend to them within a post request after I get this working.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like things are timing out because you've got a long-running generator running inside of a request.

You usually don't want to do something like this in real-time, and instead want to either pre-scrape this information for each student, then store it in a database, or do it asynchronously with a tool like [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

Also, I noticed another issue at first glance:

The URL you're hitting initially is not valid. You are hitting the URL `https://ps01.bergen.org`, but you want to hit the URL `https://ps01.bergen.org/public/`

Hope this helps!